# 2 child modules access the same component in Angular error occured

Tags: javascript, angular

i have this psuedo code structure in my angular project.

**wrapper.module** 
**Wrapper.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
 declaration: [WrapperComponent.ts]
 imports: [
   WrapperRouting.module
 ]
})
```

**wrapper-routing.module.ts** 
**WrapperRouting.module**

```
routes = [
 {
   path: '',
   component: wrapper.component.ts ,
   children: [
    { path: '', loadChildren: Component1.module.ts},
    { path: '2', loadChildren: Component2.module.ts},
   ]
 }
];
```

**component1.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
   declaration: [Component1Component, ShowTableComponent]
   imports: [
     Component1Routing.module
   ]
 })
```

**component1.component.ts**

```
<show-table></show-table>
```

**component2.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
   declaration: [Component2Component, ShowTableComponent]
   imports: [
     Component2Routing.module
   ]
 })
```

**component2.component.ts**

```
<show-table></show-table>
```

Im trying first to declar the ShowComponent in Component1.module.ts and Component2.module.ts however I got an error that `ShowComponent is declared in two module.`

Then, tried to put in the the parent module which is Wrapper.module.ts the error would be: `ShowComponent is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.`

Can someone help me, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify how you are defining the parent-child relationship between all of these modules. Because there is no specific way to depict a parent-child relationship between modules in angular.

If you want to use the
`<show-table></show-table>`
in component1.module and component2.module, you have to add the wrapper.module in the imports array of both modules i.e. component1.module and component2.module and add the `ShowComponent` in the exports array of Wrapper.module.

After which your respective code will become as follows

**Component1.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
     Component1
   ],
   imports: [
     WrapperModule
   ]
})
export class Component1Module { }
```

**Component2.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
     Component2
   ],
   imports: [
     WrapperModule
   ]
})
export class Component2Module { }
```

**wrapper.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
     ShowComponent
   ],
   exports: [
     ShowComponent
   ]
})
export class WrapperModule { }
```

P.S. This method is used when you have to use a component from a different module in the HTML of a component. If you are using `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` you don't have to worry about importing the modules to use a component. You can just specify the name of the component in the routes array.

Do let me know if my answer helped you!

Comment: i updated my question, but the wrapper module is supposed to be a parent route and the 2 component modules are child routes, if i import the wrapper module in two different modules it will cause circular dependency

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, there is one more solution you can try. 
You can create a new `ShowTableModule` in which `ShowTableComponent` is declared in the `declarations:[ShowTableComponent]` array and exported from the `ShowTableModule` module as in `exports:[ShowTableComponent]` and then import `ShowTableModule` in the imports array of both components modules. This way you get to retain the parent-child route hierarchy and use the `ShowTableComponent` in the template